# Why Grand parent virtual function is called in C#

Tags: c#, oop

I have the following code. Can anybody answer why base-show method is called not the  derive- show is called in this case. How memory allocation will be done in this case for the derive and base class's show functions.

```
class OverrideAndNew : Derive
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        Derive obj = new Derive1();
        obj.Show();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class Base
{
    public virtual void Show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base - Show");
    }
}

class Derive : Base
{
    protected virtual void Show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derive - Show");
    }
}

class Derive1 : Derive
{
    protected override void Show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derive1 - Show");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Because you called it. You cannot modify access modifiers when you override a method. So basically, Derive1 overrode the Show method of Derive. But derive never overrode that of Base. So there is only one public Show method, the one implemented in Base.

What you probably meant to do was:

```
class OverrideAndNew
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Derive obj = new Derive1();
        obj.Show();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class Base
{
    public virtual void Show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base - Show");
    }
}

class Derive : Base
{
    public override void Show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derive - Show");
    }
}

class Derive1 : Derive
{
    public override void Show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derive1 - Show");
    }
}
```

Note that the method signature stays the same. It's always public because Base said it has to be public. It's always the same name, return type and parameters (none in this case).

Comment: Just to add to nvoigt's answer from MSDN documentation on Protected modifier "The protected keyword is a member access modifier. A protected member is accessible within its class and by derived class instances.". Therefore by calling the method on the object you are accessing the public method (i.e. Base)

Answer (score 0):

Your protected method is not overriding `Base.Show`, it is merely hiding it. You need to declare `Show` in `Derive` with the same access modifier (i.e. public) and use the `override` keyword to explicitly declare that you intend to override the method.

Note that there is a compiler warning produced by this program saying as much:

> 'Derive.Show()' hides inherited member 'Base.Show()'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.

A separate question is why this is only a warning and not an error. That is because C# is designed to minimize the so-called brittle base class problem. If `Base` is in one assembly and `Derive` is in another (possibly produced by different teams or even different companies) then it would be undesirable from writer of `Derive`'s perspective if version 2 of `Base` added a new method `Show` that broke the existing code in `Derive`. Therefore it is only a warning, not an error.